# React Router nested routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I have routes:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="/about/Us" component={AboutUs} />
  <Route path="/about/Company" component={AboutCompany} />
</Switch>
```

I would like the /about route to show about component and its children (AboutUs and AboutCompany) but the /about route is only rendering About component. How can I fix that? I have react-router 4

Comment: Currently, you are asking react-router to decide between the three routes and choose one, this is what `Switch` does.  Is that not the behaviour you want?

Comment: If you want to render all three components in /about then you don't need to separate out routing, You can do it like <div><AboutUs /> <AboutCompany /> </div> in About component.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can achieve it.

1. Creating nested routes from routes.js/jsx
2. Creating nested routes from the parent component (about.js/jsx)

If it is from routes.js/jsx

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about" component={About}>
    <Route path="/about/Us" component={AboutUs} />
    <Route path="/about/Company" component={AboutCompany} />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

If it is from routes.js/jsx

```
//Routes.jsx/js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
</Switch>
```

and

```
//About.jsx/js
<Switch>
    <Route path="/about/Us" component={AboutUs} />
    <Route path="/about/Company" component={AboutCompany} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
   <Route path="/about/Us" component={AboutUs} />
   <Route path="/about/Company" component={AboutCompany} />
</Switch>
```

You need to add the exact keyword to About parent path.